# DXF code - 3D polylines

Tags: autocad, cad, dxf

I need a sample DXF code, as clean as possible, to fill with coordinates to draw 3D polylines. I've been able to do this with simple lines, but I'm struggling to do this with 3D polylines. I've tried it a few times, but it did not work. I do not work in the field and I need this to complete a scientific research. The idea is to generate a drawing from GPS coordinates. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To keep it simple create a minimal DXF R12 file, the advantage of DXF R12 is the minimalistic overall structure and
you don't need handles. Only the ENTITIES SECTION is required:

Important: comments like ""<<< some comment" has to removed in the final file.

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0       <<< 1. POLYLINE entity starts here
POLYLINE
...
0
VERTEX
...
0
VERTEX
...
0
SEQEND
0       <<< 2. POLYLINE entity starts here
POLYLINE
...
0
VERTEX
...
0
VERTEX
...
0
SEQEND
0       <<< end of section marker
ENDSEC
0       <<< end of file marker
EOF
```

The POLYLINE entity is one of two entities which requires more than one entity, the INSERT entity is the other one.

```
0        <<< POLYLINE entity
POLYLINE
8        <<< layer group code required
0        <<< layer '0'
62       <<< color group code not required
1        <<< Color number
66       <<< entities follow flag
1        <<< always 1, POLYLINE without vertices is pointless
70       <<< flags, see reference
8        <<< this is a 3D polyline
0        <<< 1. VERTEX entity
VERTEX
8        <<< layer group code required
0        <<< ALWAYS the same as POLYLINE layer!
70       <<< flags
32       <<< 3D polyline vertex
10       <<< x-coord group code
4.0      <<< x-coord value
20       <<< y-coord group code
3.0      <<< y-coord value
30       <<< z-coord group code
2.0      <<< z-coord value
0        <<< 2. VERTEX entity
VERTEX
8
0
70
32
10
8.0
20
5.0
30
0.0
0        <<< 3. VERTEX entity
VERTEX
8
0
70
32
10
2.0
20
4.0
30
9.0
0        <<< required SEQEND entity
SEQEND
```

DXF reference for POLYLINE: http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-ABF6B778-BE20-4B49-9B58-A94E64CEFFF3

DXF reference for VERTEX: http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-0741E831-599E-4CBF-91E1-8ADBCFD6556D

If you can use Python, look at my ezdxf package: https://ezdxf.mozman.at/

Create a minimal DXF R12 file with the r12writer context manager:

```
from ezdxf.r12writer import r12writer

with r12writer("YourFile.dxf") as dxf:
    dxf.add_polyline([(4, 3, 2), (8, 5, 0), (2, 4, 9)])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just saved me